# How do I log all of the fields in my PageModel from ASP.NET Core into Honeycomb/OpenTelemetry

Tags: asp.net-core

I've managed to get Honeycomb.io setup with my ASP.NET Core application, but I can't figure out how to get it to log the full PageModel when a user posts the form.

(This is the information I actually want, so I can see how people are using the product, and debug any 500s)

Any ideas/suggestions most appreciated!

Comment: can this sample help you? https://github.com/honeycombio/honeycomb-opentelemetry-dotnet/tree/main/examples/aspnetcore

Comment: and [this document](https://docs.honeycomb.io/getting-data-in/opentelemetry/dotnet-distro/) could you pls take a look at it?